# Check available layers in .dwg file

Tags: python, win32com, autocad, autolisp, dwg

I need to programmatically check whether a layer exists in an AutoCAD drawing. I am aware that it is straightforward to get the job done using a `.dxf`, like this:

```py
In [77]: import win32com.client
    ...: import ezdxf
    ...: import os

In [78]: folder = r'C:\path\to\my\folder'
    ...: filename = 'my_file'

In [79]: dxf_path = os.path.join(folder, filename + '.dxf')

In [80]: dxf = ezdxf.readfile(dxf_path)

In [81]: '0' in dxf.layers
Out[81]: True
```

But what if I want to check the available layers on a `.dwg` file? I made this attempt, which did not work because the `SendCommand` method returns `None`:

```py
In [82]: acad = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")

In [83]: dwg_path = os.path.join(folder, filename + '.dwg')

In [84]: dwg = acad.Documents.Open(dwg_path)

In [85]: dwg.SendCommand('(tblsearch "layer" "0") ') is not None
Out[85]: False
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether the following returns a layer object or an exception:

```
dwg.Layers.Item('0')
```

Or alternatively, iterate over all Layer objects within the `Layers` collection and set a flag variable or return if the `Name` property of the Layer matches the name of the layer that you seek.